# Ignoring import errors by Typescript in monorepo

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a monorepo (Turborepo) where a Next.js app package is importing various components from a shared package. That shared package is not compiled, it is simply a package containing various components imported directly by apps in the monorepo.

The problem is that those shared components have imports like this:

`import Link from 'next/link'`

TypeScript reacts, because it cannot see packages like `next/link` from within the shared components package (it does not have a node_modules). And I use pnpm, so most external npm packages are only visible to the package that uses them, they are not hoisted to the root of the monorepo.

Is there a good solution that tells typescript to not throw an error on those, kind of treating them as peersDeps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the tsconfigs.ts `paths` [configuration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) to solve your issue.

By adding the `paths` option like this, typescript will be able to properly resolve the import then.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "next/link": ["packages/next-link/index.ts"] // should match the location of your package
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that really a good solution though? You will effectively tie an independent shared components package into one of the app packages. So it's no longer decoupled. Feels wrong, what do you think?

Comment: True, but the other options I can think of is not necessarily better. You could create a shared typing file where you would declare the "next/link" module and it's types. You would avoid the coupling of the components, but you would have to handle two different source of truths and maintain the typing file when "next/link" is updated which is worse IMO and can easily introduce bugs if not maintained properly.
So I think the `paths` solution is best.

Comment: What do plugin developers do, when the package they are working on is meant to be consumed by other apps? I assume they will have peerDependencies where all the packages they import are listed. I tried listing `next/link` as a peerDependency but the error did not disappear.

Comment: Perhaps I have to look into micro-frontends, where dependency sharing is possible. Though I have a sneaking suspicion there is a much easier way to do this. Feels like a common scenario.

Comment: Lastly, this seems to indicate that using paths to map to a node_modules folder (in another internal monorepo project) is a bad idea: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/reference.html#paths

Comment: Adding a couple of conclusions here: 1) TypeScript encourages using `imports` instead of path aliases (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/reference.html#paths). 2) The actual best practice for the OP, is probably to install the missing dependencies in the shared components project, as a `devDependency`. We only need the types from the imported package, but it seems to make sense to install it as a devDep since we need the types for development. Also confirmed here: https://github.com/ezolenko/rollup-plugin-typescript2/issues/277#issuecomment-1112504639

Comment: Perhaps add those points to the answer, so others can reap the benefit :)